# Confluence REST search API could not parse cql

Tags: confluence-rest-api

```
In [50]: r = confluence.search(cql=f'title contains "Agent Alert - {event_name}" and label = "agent-event"')

# prints the params of the request
{'cql': 'title contains "Agent Alert - SYS_THRESHOLD_REACHED" and label = "agent-event"', 'expend': 'body.view'}
```

And I get this error

```
In [49]: r.content
Out[49]: b'{"statusCode":400,"data":{"authorized":false,"valid":true,"allowedInReadOnlyMode":true,"errors":[],"successful":false},"message":"Could not parse cql : title contains \\"Agent Alert - SYS_THRESHOLD_REACHED\\" and label = \\"agent-event\\"","reason":"Bad Request"}'
```

However I tried using the exact string in confluence webUI and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to work it out...

1. it doesn't seem to like `contains` in the API, so have to use `~`
2. the spaces need to be replaced with `+` within the title search

so turned out this is what is accepted

`title~"Agent+Alert+-+SYS_THRESHOLD_REACHED" and label="agent-event"`